# IF THEN on a Dataframe in r with LAG

Tags: r, dataframe, lag

I have a dataframe with multiple columns, but two columns in particular are interesting for me.
Column1 contains values 0 and a number (>0)
Column2 contains numbers as well.

I want to create 21 new columns containing new information from Column2 given Column1.

So when Column1 is positive (not 0) I want the first new column, Column01, to take the value from Column2 that goes 10 back. and Column02 goes 9 back,.. Column11 is the exact same as Column2 value.. and Column21 is 10 forward.

For example

```
  Column 1  Column2   Columns01 Columns02.. Columns11..Columns20 Columns21
      0        5          0         0           0          0         0
      0        2          0         0           0          0         0 
      0        0          0         0           0          0         0  
      1        3          0         0           3          5         4
      0        10         0         0           0          0         0
      0        83         0         0           0          0         0
      0        2          0         0           0          0         0
      0        5          0         0           0          0         0
      0        4          0         0           0          0         0
      1        8          0         5           8          5         3
      0        6          0         0           0          0         0
      0        5          0         0           0          0         0
      0        55         0         0           0          0         0
      0        4          0         0           0          0         0
      2        3          10       83           3          5         0
      0        2          0         0           0          0         0
      0        3          0         0           0          0         0
      0        4          0         0           0          0         0
      0        5          0         0           0          0         0
      0        3          0         0           0          0         0
      1        22         6         5          22          0         0
      0        12         0         0           0          0         0
      0        0          0         0           0          0         0
      0        5          0         0           0          0         0
```

Hope this makes sense to you and you can help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one way using the newly implemented `shift()` function from [`data.table v1.9.5`](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation):

```
require(data.table) ## v1.9.5+
setDT(dat)                                                      ## (1)
cols = paste0("cols", sprintf("%.2d", 1:21))                    ## (2)
dat[, cols[1:10] := shift(Column2, 10:1, fill=0)]               ## (3)
dat[, cols[11] := Column2]                                      ## (4)
dat[, cols[12:21] := shift(Column2, 1:10, fill=0, type="lead")] ## (5)
dat[Column1 == 0, (cols) := 0]                                  ## (6)
```

1. Assuming `dat` is your *data.frame*, `setDT(dat)` converts it to a *data.table*, by reference (the data is not copied physically to a new location in memory, for efficiency).
2. Generate all the column names.
3. Generated lagged vectors of `Column2` with periods `10:1` and assign it to the first 10 columns.
4. 11th column is = `Column2`.
5. Generated leading vectors of `Column2` with periods `1:10` and assign it to the last 10 columns.
6. Get indices of all the rows where `Column1 == 0`, and replace/reset all newly generated columns for those indices to `0`.

Use `setDF(dat)` if you want a *data.frame* back.

You can wrap this in a function with the values `-10:10` and choosing `type="lag"` or `type="lead"` accordingly, depending on whether the values are negative or positive.. I'll leave that to you.

Comment: Thanks! that did the trick,
Although it was a bit complicated getting "shift" working as I had to install data.table v.1.9.5, but I got it working!

Answer (score 1):

An option using `base R`

```
cols = paste0("cols", sprintf("%.2d", 1:21)) #copied from @Arun's post
m1 <- matrix(c(rep(0,10), dat1[,2]), nrow=nrow(dat1)+10+1, ncol=21, 
              dimnames=list(NULL, cols))[1:nrow(dat1),]
dat2 <- cbind(dat1,m1*dat1[,1])
```

**NOTE:** While creating `m1`, there will be a warning though.

Checking with the output from @Arun's solution (after running the codes on 'dat')

```
library(data.table)
setDF(dat) #convert the 'data.table' to 'data.frame'
all.equal(dat2, dat, check.attributes=FALSE)
#[1] TRUE
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
dat1 <- data.frame(Column1 = sample(0:1,10, replace=TRUE),
          Column2 = sample(1:5, 10, replace=TRUE))

dat <- copy(dat1)
```